# Circular Dependency with Nestjs Swagger 4

Tags: swagger, nestjs, circular-dependency

When I updated the **@nest/swagger** library to version 4, this error happened:

```sh
(node:16134) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: A circular dependency has been detected (property key: "customer"). Please, make sure that each side of a bidirectional relationships are using lazy resolvers ("type: () => ClassType").
    at SchemaObjectFactory.createNotBuiltInTypeReference (/opt/desenvolvimento/Haizen/projectx_back/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/services/schema-object-factory.js:182:19)
    at SchemaObjectFactory.mergePropertyWithMetadata (/opt/desenvolvimento/Haizen/projectx_back/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/services/schema-object-factory.js:117:25)
    at /opt/desenvolvimento/Haizen/projectx_back/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/services/schema-object-factory.js:66:35
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at SchemaObjectFactory.exploreModelSchema (/opt/desenvolvimento/Haizen/projectx_back/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/services/schema-object-factory.js:65:52)
    at SchemaObjectFactory.createNotBuiltInTypeReference (/opt/desenvolvimento/Haizen/projectx_back/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/services/schema-object-factory.js:187:37)
    at SchemaObjectFactory.mergePropertyWithMetadata (/opt/desenvolvimento/Haizen/projectx_back/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/services/schema-object-factory.js:117:25)
    at /opt/desenvolvimento/Haizen/projectx_back/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/services/schema-object-factory.js:66:35
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at SchemaObjectFactory.exploreModelSchema (/opt/desenvolvimento/Haizen/projectx_back/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/services/schema-object-factory.js:65:52)
```

My model class seems to this:

```js
@Entity()
export class Job {
.
.
.
    @ManyToOne(type => Customer, customer => customer.jobs)
    @ApiProperty({ type: Customer })
    customer: Customer;
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to declare in **@ApiProperty()** the **type** with **arrow function**, like below:

```js
@Entity()
export class Job {
.
.
.
    @ManyToOne(type => Customer, customer => customer.jobs)
    @ApiProperty({ type: () => Customer })
    customer: Customer;
}
```

Comment: I still have the problem. UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: A circular dependency has been detected (property key: "KM"). Please, make sure that each side of a bidirectional relationships are using lazy resolvers ("type: () => ClassType").

Comment: Here is my enum
enum EmissionUnitEnum {
  KM = 'km',
  MINUTE = 'minute',
  MINUTES = 'minutes',
  HOUR = 'hour',
  HOURS = 'hours',
  FIXED = 'fixed',
  SERVING = 'serving',
}

Comment: If your `Customer` class also contains `@ApiProperty` decorators, don't forget to use arrow functions there as well.

Answer (score 51):

There are at least three more cases where you get the same error message, even though they have nothing to do with bidirectional relationships:

#### Enum as type

Wrong:

```js
@ApiProperty({
    type: Salutation
})
public salutation: Salutation;
```

Correct:

```js
@ApiProperty({
    enum: Salutation
})
public salutation: Salutation;
```

#### Anonymous types

Wrong:

```js
@ApiProperty({
})
public address: {
    street: string;
    houseNumber: string;
};
```

Correct:

```js
@ApiProperty({
    type: Address
})
public address: Address;
```

#### null

Wrong:

```js
@ApiProperty({
    description: 'This always returns null for downward compatibility'
})
public someLegacyField: null;
```

Correct:

```js
@ApiProperty({
    description: 'This always returns null for downward compatibility',
    type: String; // needed to avoid error
})
public someLegacyField: null;
```

I created an issue on Github for this: https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/1475

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck for a while at this error..

Comment: The correct answer.

Comment: This is the one that worked for me.

Comment: The "Enum as type" was my issue.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone who had this problem as well, you can change the `type` key to the `enum` key on the `@ApiProperty`. This worked for me.

Comment: You are the best!

Comment: Thank you, I don't undersatnd why it works like this but it saved my day

Comment: This works only if the property is an enum. Otherwise, Swagger will display it incorrectly when exposing it.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue when I used [type interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) on nested properties of an entity

**Incorrect:**

```
export class BookLikes {
  bookLikes: {
    user: User;
    book: Book;
  }[];
}
```

Nest.js recommends using classes instead - even on nested properties:

**Correct:**

```
export class BookLikes {
  bookLikes: BookLike[];
}

export class BookLike {
  user: User;
  book: Book;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Circular dependencies**

When you have circular dependencies between classes, use a lazy function to provide the SwaggerModule with type information:

```
  export class IType {
  @ApiProperty({ type: () => Node })
    node: Node;
   }
```

**HINT**

Consider using the Swagger plugin (see Plugin section) which will automatically detect circular dependencies.

By enabling the Swagger plugin, the above class definition can be declared simply:

```
 export class IType {
        node: Node;
  }
```

see more in documentation: https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/cli-plugin

Comment: Using a function helped! Thanks a lot!  --- `@ApiProperty({ type: () => Node })`

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem using Swagger Ui Cli with **Webpack** every time I defined an **Array** property. My solution was to hardcode the ApiPropterty as Array because it seems like the plugin was not picking up on it for some reason.

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger'

export class CreateCatDto {
  @ApiProperty({ type: [String] })
  kittenNames: string[]
}
```

Docs: https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/types-and-parameters#arrays

Also if everything else fails rename your files to something the plugin does not pick up. Default: remove entity or dto from the name.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [bugfix](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/pull/810)

I managed to make my enum (ProcessCat) working like this:

```
  @ApiProperty({
    enum: ProcessCat,
    enumName: 'ProcessCat',
    isArray: true,
  })
  category: ProcessCat;
```

And thus the NestJS compiles properly.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem at it made me crazy. The answers here didn't really help. I caught it by chance, which is I defined a property as array, but without the IsArray decorator.

Bad:

```
grounding_docs: { name: string; url: string; }[];
```

Good:

```
@IsArray()
grounding_docs: { name: string; url: string; }[];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this issue recently.
In my case, I've used a few validators in the same file in my custom-validations folder. The error "A circular dependency has been detected" only appears after `nest build` and `node dist/main`.

I'm not sure if this is an issue of NestJs + Swagger after generating a build or not. Apparently, my fix was to put the validators into several files (each file contains 1 validator), it works for me.

[image]